# Moz api request is being blocked by Incapsula?

Tags: php, api

When I try to access moz api using below code

```
$accessID = 'mozscape-key';
$secretKey = 'secert key';
// Set your expires times for several minutes into the future.
// An expires time excessively far in the future will not be honored by the Mozscape API.
$expires = time() + 300;
// Put each parameter on a new line.
$stringToSign = $accessID."\n".$expires;
// Get the "raw" or binary output of the hmac hash.
$binarySignature = hash_hmac('sha1', $stringToSign, $secretKey, true);
// Base64-encode it and then url-encode that.
$urlSafeSignature = urlencode(base64_encode($binarySignature));
// Specify the URL that you want link metrics for.
$objectURL = "www.seomoz.org";
// Add up all the bit flags you want returned.
// Learn more here: https://moz.com/help/guides/moz-api/mozscape/api-reference/url-metrics
$cols = "103079215108";
// Put it all together and you get your request URL.
// This example uses the Mozscape URL Metrics API.
$requestUrl = "http://lsapi.seomoz.com/linkscape/url-metrics/".urlencode($objectURL)."?Cols=".$cols."&AccessID=".$accessID."&Expires=".$expires."&Signature=".$urlSafeSignature;
echo $requestUrl;
die;
// Use Curl to send off your request.
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
    );
$ch = curl_init($requestUrl);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$f = fopen('tte.txt','a');
fwrite($f,$content);
fclose($f);
print_r($content);
```

The out it return is below

```
<html style="height:100%">
<head>
    <meta content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW" name="ROBOTS">
    <meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection">
    <meta content="initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    <meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px;height:100%">
    <iframe frameborder="0" height="100%" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px"
    src="/_Incapsula_Resource?CWUDNSAI=9&xinfo=10-113037580-0%200NNN%20RT(1470041335360%200)%20q(0%20-1%20-1%20-1)%20r(0%20-1)%20B12(8,811001,0)%20U5&incident_id=220010400174850153-812164000562037002&edet=12&cinfo=08000000"
    width="100%">Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID:
    220010400174850153-812164000562037002</iframe>
    <meta content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW" name="ROBOTS">
    <meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection">
    <meta content="initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    <meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <iframe frameborder="0" height="100%" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px"
    src="/_Incapsula_Resource?CWUDNSAI=9&xinfo=6-31536099-0%200NNN%20RT(1470041496215%200)%20q(0%20-1%20-1%20-1)%20r(0%20-1)%20B12(8,811001,0)%20U5&incident_id=220010400174850153-224923142338658566&edet=12&cinfo=08000000"
    width="100%">Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID:
    220010400174850153-224923142338658566</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Seems like incapsula is treating request as robot. Can anyone please help me how I can fix it.

Comment: Better mask the secret key and accessID if it is something private

Comment: I did it before but then again replaced code. Fixed now. Thanks

Comment: Basiaclly it saying there is a problem with the requests, the "ROBOTS" is only for meta data, it does not think you are a robot. I'm not familiar with php but the request params should be .$accessID or just $accessID (without the dot), and why you are adding the objectURL after the URL?

Comment: The dot is to concatenate string. The final url is $requestUrl. When I add this url in browser it works and return results but with curl it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you said you are using the $requestUrl to a GET (in browser) it works fine, try combining your options array.

It should look like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $requestUrl,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Maybe You Need Agent?'
));
```

Note about agent (taken from web):

> cURL is a behemoth, and has many many possibilities. Some sites might
>   only serve pages to some user agents, and when working with APIs, some
>   might request you send a specfici user agent, this is something to be
>   aware of.

Also worth checking - you have ID of failture from Incapsula - 220010400174850153-224923142338658566

Can you check the logs and see what is there?